# how can I move up a bit a horizontal centered view in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

```
I have this XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/switch_bg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/switch_bg2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/switch_bg_off" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/switch_handle"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/switch_handle"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/switch_v"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/switch_v"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

how can I move the `switch_v` image 1dp up from where it is now?

(it's centered but the white box has shadow, then the center should be a bit upper)

[image]

Comment: have a look at 9patch images there you can better design such elements becouse it has a padding in its image und you can use the background image as real backgond of a view. Just a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/switch_bg2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/switch_bg_off" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/switch_v"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:padding="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/switch_v"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: doesn't work because of `           android:layout_centerVertical="true"`

Comment: dude adjust parent view according to your requirement where u want to put

Answer (score 0):

use `android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"` like this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/switch_v"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/switch_v"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/switch_bg2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/switch_v"
        android:layout_above="@+id/hiddenView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="visible"
         />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/hiddenView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
         />
```